# Recommended C# book for a somewhat seasoned developer

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

I've been coding c# for close to 4 years now (vb.net before that) in an ASP.NET web forms environment.  I've got the basics down but there are some things that I sometimes see that confuse me (interfaces, IEnumerable, IQueryable, reflection, etc..) that I'd like to grasp.  I'm currently using c# 3.0 and will probably be moving to c# 4 in the next year or so.  I'm currently learning MVC.

At my point in my programming career, what books, blogs, or resources could you guys recommend?  Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go deep.  Read up and understand the internals of how the CLR works:

[CLR Via C#, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) by Jeffrey Richter

And understand the latest\greatest C# language features:

[C# in Depth, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471), by Jon Skeet

Comment: Good call on the Richter book, I have an older edition and its excellent.  Also, there is a newer version of it available than what you've got linked there:
http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Dev-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: if the dude doesn't know interfaces, I think that stuff may be a bit much

Comment: Actually CLR via C# covers Interfaces in depth. See p. 311.

Comment: +1 because of Jeffrey Richter's book *CLR via C# (Third Edition)* ; it's really an awesome book, with lots of good stuff; personally I think it's a good reference, and drpcken should definitely give it a try. Also, the Third Edition covers Threading, which was another reason why I bought the book.

Answer (score 5):

> what books, blogs, or resources could
> you guys recommend?

These are my favorite C#/ASP.NET blogs, although honestly it seems like blogging has lost serious steam over the last year or so.  Guess its the twitter influence.

Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

Steve Sanderson: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/

Steve Michelotti: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923145141/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/Default.aspx)

K. Scott Allen: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/Default.aspx

Jon Galloway: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/default.aspx

ScottGu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx

Stack Overflow superstar Jon Skeet: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx

Jeremy Miller: http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/default.aspx (jaded and grumpy lately but still worthwhile reading)

I can't give any book recommendations as my technical book purchases are typically stuff that I'm beginner level at and trying to improve (jQuery and WPF being the most recent).  Abrams CLR Framework Design Guidelines are a very worthwhile and interesting read but dated and I'm sure there's better stuff out there for what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

- [The C# Programming Language (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321562992)
  When you need a chapter that:

> *"...defines the syntax, order of evaluation of operands and operators,
> and the meaning of expressions."*

- [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell and C# 3.0 in a
  Nutshell](https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) : When you need it in a nutshell.

of course...

- [The
  MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908190346/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)
  : Gets better every year.

-edit-

I almost forgot...

- [Concurrent Programming on
  Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) : Because your going to need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Real World Functional Programming (with examples in C# and F#)
by Matt P. and Jon S. has changed the way I write C# code forever.

Even if you never write any F# code, writing C# in a functional programming style is often helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be stuck only in C# and .NET; think about the bigger picture of computing, that's what I've done. Algorithms are the most important, as they govern how things like IQueryable and the other sorting interfaces work.

[Algorithmics: The Spirit of Computing (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117840)

Also worth looking at:

[The Architecture of Computer Hardware and Systems Software: An Information Technology Approach](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Architecture-Computer-Hardware-Systems-Software/dp/0471073253/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279759773&sr=8-1)

These are some course material I've come by, and I've really enjoyed them so far. I also am a big fan of C#, but I've benefited from getting down (low level) and dirty with these books.

One other one worth mentoning is:

[Engines of Logic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Engines-Logic-Mathematicians-Origin-Computer/dp/0393322297/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1279759992&sr=1-1)

This covers the history of computing and software, via some mathematical geniuses from the last century and before. People like Liebniz and Goedel, Von Neuman and Alan Turing.

Hope you find something interesting there. It's a bit off-topic for C# but for flexing the computer brain muscles, they're really good.

Answer (score 1):

Nice books which I recommend

[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)

[Microsoft Visual C# 2010: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0538479515)

[Professional C# 4.0 and .NET 4 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470502258)

[Visual C# 2008 How to Program (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013605322X)

[MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908190346/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC beginners book get [ASP.NET MVC 2.0 cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690308). Its just for beginners and to learn core concepts of asp.net mvc 2.0 its very good.